# How can I hide 'private' methods with JSDoc Typescript Declarations?

Tags: javascript, typescript, private, jsdoc, .d.ts

Let's say I have a JavaScript class

```js
/**
 * @element my-element
 */
export class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  publicMethod() {}
  /** @private */
  privateMethod() {}
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

and a declaration file, generated using `declaration` and `allowJs`:

```js
export class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  publicMethod(): void;
  /** @private */
  privateMethod(): void
}
```

I also, in a post-build script, concat this to the declaration file:

```js
declare global { interface HTMLElementTagNameMap { 'my-element': MyElement; } }
```

When using this element in a typescript file, I get access to `privateMethod` in autocomplete.

```js
import 'my-element'
const me = document.createElement("my-element")
me.// autocompletes `privateMethod`
```

How can I instruct `tsc` to mark as private any methods, fields, or properties that are annotated with the `@private` JSDoc tag?

Answer (score 6):

According to the JSDoc documentation, using `/** @private */` is the correct syntax, but this is not how TypeScript handles it. You will need to leverage TypeScripts syntax to handle this, it will not work with JSDoc alone.

[TypeScript 3.8 and up supports ES6 style private fields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#ecmascript-private-fields). You can denote a private field using the `#` symbol at the beginning of your method as such:

```js
class Animal {
  #name: string;
  constructor(theName: string) {
    this.#name = theName;
  }
}

// example

new Animal("Cat").#name;
Property '#name' is not accessible outside class 'Animal' because it has a private identifier.
```

Alternatively, [TypeScript also allows you to declare a field as private](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-typescripts-private) using the `private` marker and will provide the desired result. Doing this will not show the `privateMethod` during autocompletion (at least for it me it does not).

```js
/**
 * @element my-element
 */
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  publicMethod() {}
  /** @private */
  private privateMethod() {}
}

let element = new MyElement()

element.privateMethod()
// Error: Property 'privateMethod' is private and only accessible within class 'MyElement'.
```

Here is an example of this working with VS Code intellisense.

[image]

Comment: If you use the `['privateMethod']` syntax, VS Code will autocomplete private methods

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using correct version of typescript. **Typescript 3.8** added [support for this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8/#jsdoc-modifiers), using **Typescript 3.8 or heigher** should support @private jsdoc modifier.

You can use `tsc -h` to get information about installed version of typescript compiler.

Comment: I just tried with TypeScript `4.0.3`: doing `@private` on a function argument doesn't hide it from IntelliSense.

Comment: @brillout I am not sure, I checked in my workspace with `4.03` and it seems working. I have added this stackblitz, if you can take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gygcmw. I have `my-element.js` with same declaration as you and `test.ts` where I am trying to use MyElement and vscode does not expose private variable and method there.

Comment: Your example shows a private class method - what I'm trying to do is to hide a function argument from IntelliSense. (OP asked about private class methods hence I will reward you the bounty.) Concretely: I'm trying to hide `__INTERNAL_universalAdapter` from the user: https://github.com/reframejs/wildcard-api/blob/32b15b73720b50530da743cebc60a3e8f928e345/server/WildcardServer.ts#L115-L118

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I wasn't aware about that. May be you want to add feature request to typescript repo on github?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `@ignore` annotation for those methods and classes you wish to exclude from documenting.

> The @ignore tag indicates that a symbol in your code should never appear in the documentation.

```
/**
 * @class
 * @ignore
 */
function Jacket() {
    /** The jacket's color. */
    this.color = null;
}

/**
 * @namespace
 * @ignore
 */
var Clothes = {
    /**
     * @class
     * @ignore
     */
    Jacket: function() {
        /** The jacket's color. */
        this.color = null;
    }
};
```

More on this here: https://jsdoc.app/tags-ignore.html

Comment: FYI - as of 2020-09-12, the `@ignore` JSDoc tag is not supported by VS Code. You can add it to a type declaration but VSCode doesn't actually hide that type from IntelliSense autocomplete. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html.